# How do I get rid of my current branch, and pull in the latest revision from trunk in Bazaar?

Tags: launchpad, bazaar

Usually I just `rm -r` the Branch Folder, and reperform a `bzr branch` command when I want to chuck everything and start with the latest revision in . What is the proper way to do this though, without having to delete my branch folder?

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
bzr shelve 
bzr uncommit
bzr pull --overwrite
```

---

```
--overwrite
    Ignore differences between branches and overwrite unconditionally
```